# why isnt this background-origin working?

Tags: css

I'm messing around with the background origin property buy it doesnt seem to be working why? From my understanding background-origin dictates the paint area of the box-model, I would assume this should show the blue padding but it's not and I'm sure what it is that I'm doing wrong.
https://jsfiddle.net/36trf972/18/

```
div{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px dashed red;
  padding: 10px;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: content-box;//not working-why?
   background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("panda.jpg");
  }
```

Comment: Your question is very relevant when working with the `background-origin` property, and I noticed that none of the previous answers address the 'why' in your question.  I hope my answer will help to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `px` instead of `center`.
2. I use `background-repeat:no-repeat;` for you to see result better.

```css
div{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px dashed red;
  padding: 10px;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-origin: content-box;//not working-why?
  background-size: cover;
  background-position:50px 50px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer why background-origin isn't working, it just provides a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the property:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Cover tells the browser to make sure the image always covers the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges.

Also, add:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

To prevent any repetition.

Answer (score 0):

When working with `background-origin` it's important to understand what it does (and what it doesn't do), to get the expected results.

[`background-origin`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#background-origin) specifies whether positioning of the background image should be **relative to** the *padding box*, *border box*, or *content box*.  It does not crop or hide any part of the image.  (That's what `background-crop` is for.)

So `background-origin` is actually behaving as expected your example:

```
background-origin: content-box // position relative to content box
background-position: center    // position center of image at center of content
```

The image center is positioned at the **center** of the **content box**. From there it extends to all sides.

It happens to be that in your example, the center of the content box is the exact same spot as center of padding box or border box, because you have equal widths for border and padding on all sides.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `background-repeat:repeat` along with the `background-origin:content-box` ..It just won't work.

For all other `background-origin` such as `border-box` and the `padding-box` the repeat option would work just perfectly fine..

If you are trying to fill the content with the background the only option for you is use `cover` in  `background-size`..

The best solution comes if you are willing to write an extra piece of code in html by just giving a container element like ***`div`*** for all the content that you need and just fill it with the background..

Answer (score 0):

the background-origin property specifically applies to background images, not background colors.